# Resizing bitmap with inSampleSize <2 or in other way without running into OoM

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-imageview

I have large zoomable bitmaps with text, that I want to resize a little bit. Easiest way is to use inSampleSize, but the minimum value for it to work is 2, which is not acceptable (resizing image in half basically makes text unreadable).

createScaledBitmap works OK, but because of Android slow garbage collection for bitmaps, I sometimes run in to OutOfMemory in methods that follows it (I'm calling createBitmap after decode).

So, I wonder is there a way to reduce size of bitmap not in half and without memory issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome in my personal hell...

I am working with 2 bitmaps, one is a scaled version of the original which is scaled to fit on the screen. When I want to zoom into to make the text better readable, I switch to the original bitmap which will be used for zooming.

All my experience with huge bitmaps leads to one solution: Handle the complete life cycle of a bitmap by yourself. Don't just set a bitmap reference to null, recycle it before you release the reference. Also catch possible OOME and free memory there. Clean up everything and try the last bitmap decoding again.

I have multiple calls like this:

```
try {
    try {
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri, mOptions);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        freeMemory();
        // retry
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri, mOptions);
    }
}
catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    Log.e("THREAD", "FATAL OOME ..." + mPageNumber, e);
}
```

Comment: How do you free memory in that case? I dont't really have other bitmaps to recycle except the one i'm working with.

Comment: Than you should consider the fact, that the image is simply to big. You could try to provide it in tiles so you can work with smaller peaces. In my experience: My N1 has not much memory available, the Galaxy Tab has more and the Xoom tops everything. So working with bitmaps, you should chose a smaller, earlier device like a N1 for testing. If it works there without throwing OOME, you should have a stable app...